# how to interpret training results

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, mobilenet

I'm new in deep learning, so I'm trying to learn more and more about everything, so I tried to execute a code from github about liveness face detection,so when I did train that model with mobilenet I did get this graphs ans this results, so how can I extract Informations and interpret them :[model accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhNhB.png)

[model loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p46A.png)

and I get this confusion matrix with the classification report :
Confusion Matrix

```
[[1436  234]

 [  14 1461]]

Classification Report

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.99      0.86      0.92      1670

           1       0.86      0.99      0.92      1475

    accuracy                           0.92      3145

   macro avg       0.93      0.93      0.92      3145

weighted avg       0.93      0.92      0.92      3145
```

and here it's the code that I executed:

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from keras.layers import Dense,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

INIT_LR = 1e-5
BS = 32
EPOCHS = 20

# MobileNetV2
base_model = keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(input_shape=None, alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, pooling=None, classes=2)

x=base_model.output # a luat outputul inainte de FC
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(512,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 3
preds=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation

# specify the inputs
# specify the outputs
# now a model has been created based on our architecture
new_model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=preds)

# check the model architecture
for i,layer in enumerate(new_model.layers):
  print(i,layer.name)

# We are not using weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
for layer in new_model.layers:
    layer.trainable=True

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../db_faces/train',
                                                 target_size=(64,64),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=BS,
                                                 class_mode='binary',
                                                 shuffle=True)

validation_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../db_faces/test',
                                                 target_size=(64,64),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=BS,
                                                 class_mode='binary',
                                                 shuffle=False)

# Adam optimizer
adam_opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
# loss function will be binary cross entropy
# evaluation metric will be accuracy
new_model.compile(optimizer=adam_opt, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

step_size_train = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
step_size_validation = validation_generator.samples // validation_generator.batch_size
H = new_model.fit(train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                   validation_data = validation_generator,
                   validation_steps = step_size_validation,
                   epochs=EPOCHS)

# save the network to disk
print("[INFO] serializing network and save it to disk...")
new_model.save('liveness.model')

print("[INFO] Class indices")
labels = (train_generator.class_indices)
print(labels)

# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(H.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(H.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(H.history['loss'])
plt.plot(H.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

Y_pred = new_model.predict(validation_generator, validation_generator.samples // BS + 1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Fake', 'Real']
print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
```

Comment: What exactly isn't clear to you?

Comment: Your class mode should have been categorical as you use softmax: `class_mode='categorical'`

Comment: @Gulzar I'm still learning , so my question is how to interpret this results? how to know whether if the results are good or not ? that's what I'm trying to get

Comment: @Frightera okey I will change class mode, I taught I must use binary class because I'm working on two classes fake and real ( I ran a face antispoof liveness detection)

Comment: Ah you were using sparse cross entropy, then it should be `class_mode = 'sparse'`. Yes you have two classes but your loss for multiclass classification rather than binary classification.

Comment: @Frightera okey thank you, I will run the code with sparse and give u the new results, and for the first results how should I interpret them ?

Comment: The existing answer looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

For Binary classification problem , Model performance can be validated based on Model accuracy graph result & Classification report.

1. In your result Model accuracy of train data reached to 95%  it remain stable till epoch 20 whereas for test data it keeps on oscillating between 93% to 95% from epoch 8. We can say that model is trained well for train data and test data with accuracy of 92%. The generalization power of model is good enough.
2. From Model loss graph result, both train and test data converge each other from epoch 13. If training & testing loss=0 then it is good model with higher predictive power.
3. From Classification report , Model performance can be validated by F1 score . Higher the score results in better Model.